# Moduarizing a shiny app with R and JS code

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

### Goal

I have a working shiny app that lets users write handwritten notes in a canvas which are then converted to text input. My goal is now to modularity this functionality so that I can create as my canvases as I want.

### Details

This became possible due to the Google Input Tools.

Following is the working code in 4 files:

app.R:

```
library(shiny)
 
 ui <- fluidPage(
   tags$head(
     tags$script(src = "handwriting.js"),
     tags$script(src = "handwriting.canvas.js"),
     tags$script(src = "handwriting_for_shiny.js"),
     tags$style(HTML("
       #handwritingCanvas {
         border: 1px solid #000;
         margin-top: 10px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
       }
     "))
   ),
   titlePanel("Handwriting Recognition"),
   sidebarLayout(
     sidebarPanel(
       actionButton("clear_canvas", "Clear Canvas"),
       actionButton("undo", "Undo"),
       actionButton("redo", "Redo"),
       actionButton("send", "Send"),
       textAreaInput("manual_text", "Enter Text", value = "")
     ),
     mainPanel(
       textOutput("recognized_text"),
       br(),
       tags$canvas(id = "handwritingCanvas", width = "400px", height = "200px")
     )
   )
 )
 
 server <- function(input, output, session) {
   observeEvent(input$clear_canvas, {
     session$sendCustomMessage("eraseCanvas", message = NULL)
   })
 
   observeEvent(input$undo, {
     session$sendCustomMessage("undoCanvas", message = NULL)
   })
 
   observeEvent(input$redo, {
     session$sendCustomMessage("redoCanvas", message = NULL)
   })
 
   observeEvent(input$send, {
     session$sendCustomMessage("sendCanvas", message = NULL)
 
   })
 
   observe({
     session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
   })
 
   observe({
     session$sendCustomMessage("initCanvas", message = NULL)
   })
 
   observeEvent(input$recognized_text, {
     print(input$recognized_text)
     if (!is.null(input$recognized_text)) {
       updateTextAreaInput(session, "manual_text", value = input$recognized_text)
     }
   })
 
 }
 
 shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Following three files are in the www directory:
(From github) handwriting.js: https://github.com/ChenYuHo/handwriting.js/blob/master/handwriting.js
(From github) handwriting.canvas.js: https://github.com/ChenYuHo/handwriting.js/blob/master/handwriting.canvas.js

**handwriting_for_shiny.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
         var handwritingCanvas;


     var canvas = document.getElementById('handwritingCanvas');
     handwritingCanvas = new handwriting.Canvas(canvas, 3);

     $('#clear_canvas').click(function() {
       handwritingCanvas.erase();
     });

     $('#undo').click(function() {
       handwritingCanvas.undo();
     });

     $('#redo').click(function() {
       handwritingCanvas.redo();
     });

     $('#send').click(function() {
       var trace = handwritingCanvas.trace;
       var options = {
         language: 'en',
         numOfReturn: 1
       };
       var callback = function(result, err) {
         if (err) {
           console.error(err);
         } else {
           Shiny.setInputValue('recognized_text', result[0]);
         }
       };
       handwriting.recognize(trace, options, callback);
     });

     // Enable undo and redo
     handwritingCanvas.set_Undo_Redo(true, true);

     $('#handwritingCanvas').on('mouseup', function() {
       // Removed the automatic recognition on mouseup
     });
   });
```

This works. How do I convert this into a module. I understand what I can do in the app.R code but what about the handwriting_for_shiny.js? The critical part there seems to be Shiny.setInputValue('recognized_text', result[0]); The recognized_text thing should somehow be in a namespace., i.e., wrapped in ns in the javascript code. How to do that?

### Edit

#### Solution attempt:

I created a new JS file named `handwriting_for_shiny2.js` in `www` folder, a  `mod_handwriting.R` file in `R` folder, and a new `app2.R` for testing purposes. The code in these 3 files is based on @Stéphane Laurent's answer.

Result: I tested with 2 instances of the modules. 2 canvases render. I can write only in the first one, the second on does not show any thing when I scribble in it. The send button for the first module does not show the recognized text in the textbox.

Here's the code, please let me know what I am missing:
**app2.R**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "handwriting.js"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting.canvas.js"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting_for_shiny2.js"),
    tags$style(HTML("
       #handwritingCanvas {
         border: 1px solid #000;
         margin-top: 10px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
       }
     "))
  ),
  titlePanel("Handwriting Recognition"),
  handwritingUI("module1"),
  handwritingUI("module2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  handwritingServer("module1")
  handwritingServer("module2")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**mod_handwriting.R**

```
handwritingUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton(ns("clear_canvas"), "Clear Canvas"),
      actionButton(ns("undo"), "Undo"),
      actionButton(ns("redo"), "Redo"),
      actionButton(ns("send"), "Send"),
      textAreaInput(ns("manual_text"), "Enter Text", value = ""),
      tags$canvas(id = "handwritingCanvas", width = "400px", height = "200px")
    )
  )
}


handwritingServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
    
  observeEvent(input$clear_canvas, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("clearCanvas", message = NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$send, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("sendCanvas", message = NULL)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$recognized_text, {
    if (!is.null(input$recognized_text)) {
      updateTextAreaInput(session, "manual_text", value = input$recognized_text)
    }
  })
  
  observe({
    session$onSessionEnded(stopApp)
  })
  
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("initCanvas", message = NULL)
  })
  
    }
  )
}
```

**handwriting_for_shiny2.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var handwritingCanvas;
   var canvas = document.getElementById('handwritingCanvas');
   handwritingCanvas = new handwriting.Canvas(canvas, 3);

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("clearCanvas", function() {
    handwritingCanvas.erase();
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("sendCanvas", function() {
    var trace = handwritingCanvas.trace;
    var options = {
      language: 'en',
      numOfReturn: 1
    };
    var callback = function(result, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        Shiny.setInputValue('recognized_text', result[0]);
      }
    };
    handwriting.recognize(trace, options, callback);
  });
});
```

Comment: Shiny knows about modularisation - and hence namespacing.  JavaScript does not.  So you will have to modify your JS code so that it "knows" about namespacing.  So, either (a) each instance of your module will need to create its own version of any JS function or (b) you'll need a global version that "knows" about namespacing.  I don't know enough about the API you're using to know which is best (or even possible). For example, you'll have to change `Shiny.setInputValue('recognized_text', result[0]);` to `paste0("Shiny.setInputValue('", ns(recognized_text), "', result[0]);")` or similar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some `session$sendCustomMessage` in your R code but I don't see the corresponding `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` in the JavaScript files.

If you put the action buttons in a UI module, you'll have something like that:

```r
actionButton(ns("clear_canvas"), "Clear Canvas")
```

where `ns` is `NS("theID")`. So in the JavaScript code, you'll have to replace `$("#clear_canvas")` with `$("#theID-clear_canvas")` in the click listener of this button. This is not very convenient for if you change `"theID"` in R that will not work anymore.

So, instead of defining this click listener, you could use `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` instead. That is, in the server module you'll have:

```r
mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      observeEvent(input$clear_canvas, {
        session$sendCustomMessage("eraseCanvas", message = NULL)
      })

      ......
```

and in JavaScript you'll have:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var handwritingCanvas;
   var canvas = document.getElementById('handwritingCanvas');
   handwritingCanvas = new handwriting.Canvas(canvas, 3);

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("clearCanvas", function() {
    handwritingCanvas.erase();
  });
  ......
```

In the click listener of the `#send` button you have a `Shiny.setInputValue`. So here I would do:

```r
      observeEvent(input$send, {
        session$sendCustomMessage("sendCanvas", message = id)
      })
```

and:

```js
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("sendCanvas", function(id) {
       var trace = handwritingCanvas.trace;
       var options = {
         language: 'en',
         numOfReturn: 1
       };
       var callback = function(result, err) {
         if (err) {
           console.error(err);
         } else {
           Shiny.setInputValue(id + '-recognized_text', result[0]);
         }
       };
       handwriting.recognize(trace, options, callback);
  });
```

---

## Edit

You want to use the module several times. So you have to use different ids for the canvas. You can do, in the module UI:

```r
handwritingUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton(ns("clear_canvas"), "Clear Canvas"),
      actionButton(ns("undo"), "Undo"),
      actionButton(ns("redo"), "Redo"),
      actionButton(ns("send"), "Send"),
      textAreaInput(ns("manual_text"), "Enter Text", value = ""),
      tags$canvas(id = ns("handwritingCanvas"), width = "400px", height = "200px")
    )
  )
}
```

in the module server:

```r
mod_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {

      observe({
        session$sendCustomMessage("initialize", message = id)
      })

      observeEvent(input$clear_canvas, {
        session$sendCustomMessage("eraseCanvas", message = id)
      })

      ......
```

and in JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   var handwritingCanvas = {};
   
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("initialize", function(id) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id + '-handwritingCanvas');
    handwritingCanvas[id] = new handwriting.Canvas(canvas, 3);
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("clearCanvas", function(id) {
    handwritingCanvas[id].erase();
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("sendCanvas", function(id) {
    var trace = handwritingCanvas[id].trace;
    var options = {
      language: 'en',
      numOfReturn: 1
    };
    var callback = function(result, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        Shiny.setInputValue(id + '-recognized_text', result[0]);
      }
    };
    handwriting.recognize(trace, options, callback);
  });
});
```

You'll have to send the id in all your `session$sendCustomMessage`, and in the JavaScript side you'll have to replace all your `handwritingCanvas` with `handwritingCanvas[id]`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please tell me if `tags$canvas(id = "handwritingCanvas", width = "400px", height = "200px")` line also goes in the module? I think it should. But then wouldn't I need to do `id = ns("handwritingCanvas")`? Won't that need changes in the JS function?

Comment: @umairdurrani If you do `tags$canvas(id = "handwritingCanvas")` then the id is `handwritingCanvas`, not `ns(handwritingCanvas)`. So don't use the `ns`.

Comment: In my understanding, all IDs in a module should be namespaced. So, if I am placing `tags$canvas` in my module UI, wouldn't it need to be namespaced? Otherwise, it won't render.

Comment: @umairdurrani It will render, don't worry. Only the ID *of the shiny inputs* must be namespaced. Otherwise they won't be detected in the module server, that's the only reason they must be namespaced. But they will render. You don't have `input$handwritingCanvas` in the module server, so no worry. Don't use the `ns` for canvas id, otherwise you will have to deal with this id in the JavaScript file.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I tried your suggested steps, but it did not work out. Please see my attempt at the solution.

Comment: @umairdurrani Please re-read my answer more carefully. You must have `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("sendCanvas", function(id) {......` and `Shiny.setInputValue(id + '-recognized_text', result[0]);` inside of it and `session$sendCustomMessage("sendCanvas", message = id)`. For the canvas which doesn't work, this is normal because the two canvas have the same id, which is not allowed in HTML.

Comment: @umairdurrani See my edit for how to deal with the multiple canvas.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you so much for all your guidance and help.