# Javascript code does not work within nested modules in Shiny R

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

This question is a follow-up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77991960/moduarizing-a-shiny-app-with-r-and-js-code/77994651?noredirect=1#comment137503368_77994651) which was answered.

### Goal

Enable handwriting to text conversion in a shiny app while using nested modules.

### This works

Three files are relevant:

- handwriting_for_shiny2.js (placed in `www` folder)
- mod_handwriting.R  (placed in `R` folder; this is a module that utilizes the js function)
- app.R (placed in main app folder)

Running `app.R` shows a canvas where you can write with a stylus and it is converted to text when the "Send" button is clicked. There also Undo, Redo, and Clear canvas buttons.

### This does not work

I then introduced another module (`mod_simple.R`) that utilizes the module `mod_handwriting.R`. Then I created another app file called `app2.R` where I used the `mod_simple.R`. But this time the buttons don't work. Although, I can still write in the canvas.

#### Code

Here is all the code:
**handwriting_for_shiny2.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var handwritingCanvas = {};

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("initialize", function(id) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(id + '-handwritingCanvas');
    handwritingCanvas[id] = new handwriting.Canvas(canvas, 3);

     // Enable undo and redo
     handwritingCanvas[id].set_Undo_Redo(true, true);
     console.log("This is initialize function");
  });

  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("clearCanvas", function(id) {
    handwritingCanvas[id].erase();
    console.log("This is clearCanvas function");
  });

   Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("undoCanvas", function(id) {
    handwritingCanvas[id].undo();
  });

   Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("redoCanvas", function(id) {
    handwritingCanvas[id].redo();
  });


  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("sendCanvas", function(id) {
    var trace = handwritingCanvas[id].trace;
    var options = {
      language: 'en',
      numOfReturn: 1
    };
    var callback = function(result, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        Shiny.setInputValue(id + '-recognized_text', result[0]);
      }
    };
    handwriting.recognize(trace, options, callback);
  });





});
```

**mod_handwriting.R**

```
handwritingUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width = 4,
      actionButton(ns("clear_canvas"), "Clear Canvas"),
      actionButton(ns("undo"), "Undo"),
      actionButton(ns("redo"), "Redo"),
      actionButton(ns("send"), "Send"),
      textAreaInput(ns("manual_text"), "Enter Text", value = ""),
      tags$canvas(id = ns("handwritingCanvas"), width = "400px", height = "200px")
    )
  )
}


handwritingServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      observe({
        session$sendCustomMessage("initialize", message = id)
      })
    
  observeEvent(input$clear_canvas, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("clearCanvas", message = id)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$send, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("sendCanvas", message = id)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$undo, {
    print("Undo button clicked")  # Diagnostic output
    session$sendCustomMessage("undoCanvas", message = id)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$redo, {
    session$sendCustomMessage("redoCanvas", message = id)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$recognized_text, {
    if (!is.null(input$recognized_text)) {
      updateTextAreaInput(session, "manual_text", value = input$recognized_text)
    }
  })
  
  
  observe({
    session$sendCustomMessage("initCanvas", message = NULL)
  })
  
    }
  )
}
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "handwriting.js"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting.canvas.js"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting_for_shiny2.js"),
    tags$style(HTML("
       #handwritingCanvas {
         border: 1px solid #000;
         margin-top: 10px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
       }
     "))
  ),
  titlePanel("Handwriting Recognition"),
  handwritingUI("module1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  handwritingServer("module1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**mod_simple.R**

```
mod_simple_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    handwritingUI(ns("foo"))
  )
}

mod_simple_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      handwritingServer(ns("foo"))
    }
  )
}
```

**app2.R**

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "handwriting.js"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting.canvas.js"),
    tags$script(src = "handwriting_for_shiny2.js"),
    tags$style(HTML("
       #handwritingCanvas {
         border: 1px solid #000;
         margin-top: 10px;
         margin-bottom: 10px;
       }
     "))
  ),
  titlePanel("Handwriting Recognition"),
  mod_simple_ui("module1")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mod_simple_server("module1")
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Debugging the JS code:

I have put `console.log` statements in the JS code. I see both prints with `app.R` but only `This is initialize function` with `app2.R`. Somehow, the `clearCanvas` function is not triggered (and so are the other button functions). This seems to be a namespace issue. I'd appreciate any help.

### Edit

Changed the `mod_simple.R` by removing `ns`in the server part:

```
mod_simple_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    handwritingUI(ns("foo"))
  )
}

mod_simple_server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      handwritingServer("foo")
    }
  )
}
```

But with this change, I lost the ability to write inside the canvas. Also, the console shows this error:

```
shinyapp.ts:442  TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getContext')
    at new handwriting.Canvas (handwriting.canvas.js:19:24)
    at e.<anonymous> (handwriting_for_shiny2.js:6:29)
    at e.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:866:40)
    at m (shinyapp.ts:5:1357)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:5:4174)
    at Generator.next (shinyapp.ts:5:2208)
    at f0 (shinyapp.ts:6:99)
    at s (shinyapp.ts:7:194)
    at shinyapp.ts:7:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
(anonymous) @ shinyapp.ts:442
shinyapp.ts:442  TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'erase')
    at e.<anonymous> (handwriting_for_shiny2.js:14:27)
    at e.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:866:40)
    at m (shinyapp.ts:5:1357)
    at Generator.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:5:4174)
    at Generator.next (shinyapp.ts:5:2208)
    at f0 (shinyapp.ts:6:99)
    at s (shinyapp.ts:7:194)
    at shinyapp.ts:7:364
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at e.<anonymous> (shinyapp.ts:7:97)
(anonymous) @ shinyapp.ts:442
m @ shinyapp.ts:5
(anonymous) @ shinyapp.ts:5
(anonymous) @ shinyapp.ts:5
f0 @ shinyapp.ts:6
c @ shinyapp.ts:7
Promise.then (async)
f0 @ shinyapp.ts:6
s @ shinyapp.ts:7
Promise.then (async)
f0 @ shinyapp.ts:6
s @ shinyapp.ts:7
Promise.then (async)
f0 @ shinyapp.ts:6
s @ shinyapp.ts:7
Promise.then (async)
f0 @ shinyapp.ts:6
s @ shinyapp.ts:7
Promise.then (async)
f0 @ shinyapp.ts:6
s @ shinyapp.ts:7
Promise.then (async)
f0 @ shinyapp.ts:6
s @ shinyapp.ts:7
Promise.then (async)
f0 @ shinyapp.ts:6
s @ shinyapp.ts:7
```

Comment: IMHO, when you use nested modules, you don't have to namespace the id in the module server: `handwritingServer(ns("foo"))` should be `handwritingServer("foo")` instead. However I don't understand why you can see the first `console.log`.

Comment: Ah no, I understand actually. I'm right: don't use `ns` to call the nested module server.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Thanks again for your help. I tried removing `ns` but the console throws an error. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use nested modules, you don't have to namespace the id in the module server: `handwritingServer(ns("foo"))` must be replaced with `handwritingServer("foo")` instead.

And a new problem occurs. Since you do  `tags$canvas(id = ns("handwritingCanvas"), ......)` in the inner module, the id of the canvas will be `module1-foo-handwritingCanvas`. So you have to send the id `module1-foo` to the Shiny message handlers.

A convenient way to deal with this problem is to use `ns <- session$ns` in the module server, and then take `ns("")`. This will give `module1-foo-`. Note the trailing hyphen; you have to remove it. That is, you have to do:

```r
handwritingServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      
      ns <- session$ns
      prefix <- ns("") # = "module1-foo-"
      nested_id <- sub("-$", "", prefix) # remove the trailing hyphen
      
      observe({
        session$sendCustomMessage("initialize", message = nested_id)
      })
```

Comment: Oh my God! ID inception in nested modules. Thank you so much!